# Define an alias for an unknown C++ class imported from DLL

Tags: class, dll, alias, typedef

I'm getting confused by the use of dllimport on classes, and would appreciate some help !
I have built the following C++ code and packaged it a dynamic lib:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) normaldog {
    normaldog(){};
    ~normaldog(){};
    char* call() { return "woof!"; }
}

class __declspec(dllexport) stupiddog {
    stupiddog(){};
    ~stupiddog(){};
    char* call() { return "meow?"; }
}
```

Now, I want to use one of those classes in my main program (instantiate, call methods and destroy) as I'd do with an usual class. My problem is, I don't know which one I will use before runtime: I could call a *normaldog* on the first exec an a *stupiddog* on the second. I'd like to use an alias for this in my compiled code, which would be resolved at runtime.

How's the way to do it ? I'd say that *typedef* is my best bet, but I cannot find the right syntax for using it...

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

That problem is unrelated to DLLs (it would be the the same if the classes were defined in the actual program).

Typedef is not what you want. It's a completely static feature, so it won't help you resolve anything at runtime.

What you want is polymorphism. Have both classes inherit from a (possibly abstract) base class:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Dog
{
public:
    Dog() {}
    virtual ~Dog() {}

    virtual const char* Call() = 0;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) NormalDog : public Dog
{
public:
    NormalDog() {}
    ~virtual NormalDog() {}

    virtual const char* Call() { return "woof!"; }
};

class __declspec(dllexport) StupidDog : public Dog
{
public:
    StupidDog() {}
    virtual ~StupidDog() {}

    virtual const char* Call() { return "meow?"; }
};
```

You can then decide at runtime which one you want to instantiate and then use it through a Dog pointer:

```
Dog* pDog;

if (...)
    pDog = new NormalDog();
else
    pDog = new StupidDog();

pDog->Call();
```

EDIT: If you can't modify the DLL's classes, you can use this workaround:

```
class DogObject
{
public:
    DogObject() {}
    virtual ~DogObject {}
};

class NormalDogObject : public DogObject
{
private:
    NormalDog m_dog; // the DLL's NormalDog

public:
    NormalDogObject() {}
    virtual ~NormalDogObject() {}

    NormalDog& GetNormalDog() { return m_dog; }
    const NormalDog& GetNormalDog() const { return m_dog; }
};

class StupidDogObject : public DogObject
{
private:
    StupidDog m_dog; // the DLL's StupidDog

public:
    StupidDogObject() {}
    virtual ~StupidDogObject() {}

    StupidDog& GetStupidDog() { return m_dog; }
    const StupidDog& GetStupidDog() const { return m_dog; }
};
```

Then use dynamic_cast to find out the runtime type of a DogObject and call methods on it:

```
DogObject* pDog;

if (...)
    pDog = new NormalDogObject();
else
    pDog = new StupidDogObject();

if ((NormalDogObject* pNormalDog = dynamic_cast<NormalDogObject*>(pDog)) != nullptr)
    pNormalDog->Call();
else if ((StupidDogObject* pStupidDog = dynamic_cast<StupidDogObject*>(pDog)) != nullptr)
    pStupidDog->Call();
```

Of course, if all the classes have the same methods (as in this example), you can declare those methods as pure virtual in DogObject and have the derived classes implement them by delegating the calls to the DLL's classes' methods (basically wrapping everything in your own class hierarchy). Which would beg the question, why didn't the DLL's developers do that in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solves... half of my problem !

Well, the important part that I didn't explain it that the DLL is meant to be developped by external people, so I'm supposedly blind on it. I'm trying to build a generic interface that would interpret any user-defined class following my prototype. A DLL should package several of those classes, whose names would be provided to me at runtime. Is that even feasible ?

If not, I still can proceed differently, and ask the user several DLLs implementing different versions of the Dog class... Not my favourite solution, though.

Comment: Basically are you saying that you want to do what I showed but you can't modify the DLL's classes? I'll edit the answer to show a workaround.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. 
So, if I understand well: I must define a "master class" with conventional name and members (*Dog*), and use it this way on my side of the program.
The user should then implement this class *Dog* so it would instantiate different derived classes (*NormalDog*, *StupidDog*), following some user-defined keywords...
Or in other words, leave him all the problems... I like this option !